# How to create a dependent variable in regression when it does not exist in data?

Tags: regression, correlation, chi-squared-test

[image]

In ques 5, I have 10 factors which could affect purchasing decision. Now i wanted to find the co-relation between 10 factors which i will treat as Independent factors and Purchase decision which i intend to use as a dependent variable but couldn't quantify it with anything. Now in order to apply regression, i need an actual dependent variable which can be used to co-relate with other factors. How can i get around this problem or is there any other test which i can use.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Purchase decision which will be my dependent variable but it does not exist as it is in data"? You don't know the purchase decision for anyone who answered Q5?

Comment: I mean 'purchase decision'  is the variable i intend use but can't quantify it with anything. This survey is done on the Dealers who are already using a product. So to better position it in market, the influencing factors which drives the purchasing decision is what i am trying to determine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unanswerable given the data you have. You cannot create a dependent variable where there is none in the data.

Therefore, you cannot do regression.

You can compare the scores of the different variables; you can perhaps do a factor analysis or a cluster analysis or some other multivariate method.

Answer (score 2):

This is an incomplete question that does not make much sense as written.

If you don't know the purchase decision, you have nothing to analyze.